# Issue with Composed task in spring cloud data flow with oracle database

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are trying to execute the composed task from spring cloud data flow(1.2.3.RELEASE) with Oracle database for storing the status of the task/jobs. When I run the individual task or jobs it runs smoothly with out any error.
To run the conposed task as specified in the documentation I have registered composed-task-runner(1.1.0.RELEASE) as an app in the SCDF. But when I launch the composed task from SCDF it fails to launch the composed-task-runner with following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.task.app.composedtaskrunner.ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication.main(ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication.java:29) [classes!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [composedtaskrunner-task-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [composedtaskrunner-task-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [composedtaskrunner-task-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [composedtaskrunner-task-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Even I have tried adding oracle dependency in the spring-cloud-starter-task-composedtaskrunner/pom as we do in case of SCDF to make it work with Oracle but it again gives the same error. Please find the resultant pom file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task-composedtaskrunner</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Spring Cloud Starter Task Composed Task Runner</name>
<description>Contains the app for the Composed Task Starter</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.task.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>composedtaskrunner-task-app-starters-build</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-app-starter-doc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <generatedProjectHome>${session.executionRootDirectory}/apps</generatedProjectHome>
                <generatedProjectVersion>${project.version}</generatedProjectVersion>
                <bom>
                    <name>scs-bom</name>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.task.app</groupId>
                    <artifactId>composedtaskrunner-task-app-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </bom>
                <generatedApps>
                    <composedtaskrunner-task>
                        <autoConfigClass>org.springframework.cloud.task.app.composedtaskrunner.ComposedTaskRunnerConfiguration.class</autoConfigClass>
                    </composedtaskrunner-task>
                </generatedApps>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me understand what I have missed or need to add to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear how you attempted to add the Oracle-driver from the post description/pom. Without that in the classpath, it will fail with driver-not-found errors.

We have a patching procedure for the Apps. Like [stream-apps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.SR1/reference/html/_introduction.html#_patching_pre_built_applications), you'd download composed-task-runner, adjust the `pom.xml` with your proprietary Oracle-driver dependency, and finally adjust `@Import` with [`ComposedRunnerVisitorConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-task-composedtaskrunner/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/app/composedtaskrunner/configuration/ComposedRunnerVisitorConfiguration.java).

With that you'd be able to [build the App](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/docs/Clark.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#_building_the_artifacts) - verify the uber-jar to confirm the Oracle-driver is in the classpath. You can also locally run the App (`java -jar  ..`) to make sure it starts and connects to the desired Oracle DB. If it runs standalone, it will run when orchestrated from SCDF, too.

One other thing. Please make sure the `datasource` configurations are same between CTR, SCDF and the Tasks included in the CTR-graph. Unless they share the same datasource, you won't be able to visualize the executions in SCDF Dashboard - see docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#sharing-spring-cloud-dataflows-datastore-with-tasks).